# Text drawn over image is too small

Tags: ios, swift, text, draw

I'm trying to draw a resizable textView onto an image kind of like snapchat does but when I draw the label onto the image, the text is significantly smaller and more towards the top left than it should be.

```
func drawTextToImage(){

    let rect = textView.frame
    let showText = textView.text
    let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
    let attr = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    let image = UIImage(named: "3FactorPostGreen")

    //First create the rotated and transparent image with text
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height), false, 0)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.rotate (by: 45.0 * CGFloat.pi/180.0) //45˚
    }
    showText?.draw(in: CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height), withAttributes: attr)
    let rotatedImageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    //Then, draw rotated image(with text) onto the background image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height), true, 0)

    image?.draw(in: rect)
    rotatedImageWithText?.draw(in: rect)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.imageView.image = newImage
}
```

Then this was the before and after photos

Larger Text: 
[image]  [image]

Smaller Text: 
[image]  [image]

I have no idea what happens when this goes on but if anyone could explain and help that would be awesome.

Comment: could you try to increase the size of your textview and see if that changes font size ?

Comment: It does not change the font size, but it does change its x and y position or make the text line break

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the display ? It might help in seeing whats wrong.

Comment: The top row is before then after drawn image with the textview at an increased size, and the bottom row is before and after drawn image with textview at a decreased size